# Why does $b^{-3}=1/b^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following link shows how to complete the question:

> Simplify: $$ \frac{a^4}{b^{-3}}\cdot \left(a^{-2}b^{-3}\right)^2$$

However I do not understand how the workings out have gone from  $b^{-3}$ to $1/b^6$.

Also $b^{-3}$  is $b$ to power neg $3$.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: One help could be to use {} in math mode around -3 for instance.

Comment: $b^{-3} = 1 / b^3$, maybe $b^6$ came up from $b^{-3} \cdot b^{-3} = 1/b^6$.

Comment: I think the link is missing here.

Comment: Helped with some typsetting. You can see by clicking "edit" how it was written.

Comment: Multiplying numerator with numerator and denominator with denominator, you get $\left(\frac{a^4}{b^{-3}} \right)\cdot\left( \frac{a^{-2}}{b^{-3}}\right) = \frac{a^{4} \cdot a^{-2}}{b^{-3} \cdot b^{-3}} = \frac{a^{4-2}}{b^{-3-3}} = \frac{a^{2}}{b^{-6}}$.

Comment: Oh dam apparently interrupted some soul's edit effort again. Sorry man. Err I don't mean egreg, some other guy who was just some secs before me too.

Comment: $b^{-3}\ne1/b^6$, generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recall that
$$
\frac{1}{b^m}=b^{-m}
$$
for *any integer* $m$. This means that
$$
\frac{a^4}{b^{-3}}=a^4b^{-(-3)}=a^4b^3
$$
Next, for the same reason,
$$
\frac{a^{-2}}{b^{-3}}=a^{-2}b^{-(-3)}=a^{-2}b^3
$$
and your expression becomes
$$
a^4b^3a^{-2}b^3=a^{4-2}b^{3+3}=a^2b^6
$$

Comment: Thank you, this has really cleared things up for me, and will be jotted down in my book of basic maths ! very much appreciate that and sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying numerator with numerator and denominator with denominator, you get:

$$\left(\frac{a^4}{b^{-3}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a^{-2}}{b^{-3}}\right)=\frac{(a^{4})\cdot(a^{-2})}{(b^{-3})\cdot(b^{-3})}=\frac{a^{4-2}}{b^{-3-3}}=\frac{a^{2}}{b^{-6}}$$